# Keys in a MUI <ListItem> are not mandatory?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am currently working on a menu using Typescript (3.5.1), React (16.8.6), Material-Ui (v4) and CRA. I am using a `List` from material-ui. I forgot to add a `key` on my `ListItems` and had no warnings in the dev tools.

I thought keys were highly recommended in list items ? I already had warnings in other components when not providing a key to a `ListItem` so I tried to run some tests.

```
// This code shows no warning when rendered, even if no key
// was provided to the ListItem

render(){
  return(
    <List>
    {  [
        {text: 'files', icon: <FolderIcon />, path: '/my-files/'},
        {text: 'shared files', icon: <SharedIcon />, path: '/shared-files'},
      ].map(item => (
               <ListItem button>
                 <ListItemIcon>{item.icon}</ListItemIcon>
                 <ListItemText>{item.text}</ListItemText>
               </ListItem>
            ))}
       }
    <List>
  )
}
```

However :

```
// This code shows the warning "Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop." when rendered

render(){
  const items = [
                  {text: 'files', icon: <FolderIcon />, path: '/my-files/'},
                  {text: 'shared files', icon: <SharedIcon />, path: '/shared-files'},
                 ]
  return(
    <List>
     { items.map(item => (
               <ListItem button>
                 <ListItemIcon>{item.icon}</ListItemIcon>
                 <ListItemText>{item.text}</ListItemText>
               </ListItem>
            ))}
      }
    <List>
  )
}
```

I really don't understand what is the difference between those two versions, except that I am using a variable in the second example.

Anyone knows why ?

Comment: what's the warning?

Comment: Indeed I forgot to specify it. My bad. It is the classical "Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop." I am editing the original post for future people who would see this :)

Comment: I see a warning in both cases. https://codesandbox.io/s/list-key-warning-4qmlc

Comment: I now have a warning too. Don't really know what happened. Sorry for bothering both of you and thanks :)